# Optimizing jQuery code with setInterval or setTimeout

Tags: jquery, html

**Question 1:**

I have a pretty simple jQuery code. The idea is to run the code every 5 secs. This should work 24/7 every day as fast as possible and it should not require too much memory.

The amount of data which get_bio.php gets and inserts to div #bio every 5 secs is huge. I cannot reduce the amount of data. I just must optimize my code as well as possible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_bio_data = function() {
    var bio = 106;

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#bio').html(data);
    });
  };

  setInterval(get_bio_data, 5000);
});
```

So, how could I optimize my code?

**Question 2:**

Is this better than my first code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_bio_data = function() {
    var bio = 106;

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#bio').html(data);

      setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
    });
  };

  setTimeout(get_bio_data, 5000);
});
```

**Question 3:**

I used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_bio_data = function() {
    var bio = 106;

    jQuery.post("get_bio.php", {
      bio: bio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#bio').html(data);

      setTimeout(get_bio_data, 6000);
    });
  };

  setTimeout(get_bio_data, 6000);
});
```

It did run 7 hours 21 minutes 35 seconds and then it stopped. Why is that?

Comment: I would use [Server-sent events](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp) or [long-polling](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery). Or even Web sockets if you want to go the extra mile.

Comment: Tell us more about the data - is it largely the same every 5 seconds or completely different? Can you get back just the raw data, not the HTML for it? If fetching the data takes longer than 5 seconds, do you want to cancel that request and try again at the next interval? There is lots to consider here.

Comment: It is largely the same. It is all HTML code and it has to be that way. If it takes longer than 5 seconds, I would like to wait and try again asap.

Comment: If you truly want to make the load on the browser as light as possible, introduce a new intermediate server that can determine just the difference and send that to the browser whenever it wants via Websockets or Server Sent Events. The server does the polling and processing of the large amounts of data, and the browser then just gets sent the raw data for the rows to add, update or remove (or whatever), and renders it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Server Sent Events would be nice, but I need a cross browser solution.